# How to get an IP address from Mac address programmatically on Android?

Tags: android, ip-address, android-wifi, mac-address

Programmatically, I got Mac addresses of other Wifi enabled devices from my device on the same network. Same I need to apply here. Is there any apps or any other possibilities to get an IP addresses of each wifi enabled devices on the network by using those Mac addresses on Android?

Comment: You got the MAC addresses how?

Comment: I'm looking for the code to get mac address of other devices connected on same network. Can you please paste the code or link. I'm searching for while not getting the exact result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're looking for an android app, you could try [Network Discovery](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.lamatricexiste.network&hl=en) which work very well and can list all the devices on your local network with the corresponding IP and address.

If you're looking for code instead, well the application is available [on github](https://github.com/rorist/android-network-discovery#readme) and does (amongst other things ) basically the same thing than explained by Yahel : it reads /proc/net/arp .

Note : I'm NOT the author of this application.

Comment: Starting Android Q it is not possible anymore to access the /proc/net/arp file.

Answer (score 3):

This person does the exact opposite so it should work for you.

The trick is to read the ARP cache table from the device.

http://www.flattermann.net/2011/02/android-howto-find-the-hardware-mac-address-of-a-remote-host/