# Get the IP address from device Mac address (RARP) in Android

Tags: java, android, ip-address, mac-address, arp

I want to get the Dynamic IP of a device connected to the same wifi router, to which our android phone is connected to, I have searched lots of things but didn't get the answer for this, but I found I protocol known as **RARP**.

Which does the same as what I want? How can I implement this in android/java?
Can anyone help me with this?

Here is the similar : 
[Question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090387/how-to-get-an-ip-address-from-mac-address-programmatically-on-android)

But not answered exactly, is it really required to scan all devices connected to the router?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How come you know the MAC address but not the IP address?

Comment: Our devices have fixed , mac address , we have that information , we wanted to find the Dynamic IP of that device which changes everytime in the WIFI network .